# How to get focus on a page element in espresso?

Tags: android, android-espresso, hamcrest

I am trying to check/uncheck a checkbox in my espresso test using:

```
 termsAndConditionsCheckbox.check(matches(isChecked()));
 termsAndConditionsCheckbox.perform(scrollTo()).perform(click());
 termsAndConditionsCheckbox.check(matches(isNotChecked()));
```

But getting error:

```
Error performing 'scroll to' on view
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Action will not be performed because the target view does not match one or more of the following constraints:
          (view has effective visibility=VISIBLE and is descendant of a: (is assignable from class: class android.widget.ScrollView or is assignable from class: class android.widget.HorizontalScrollView))
          Target view: "AppCompatCheckBox{id=2131689839, res-name=tnc_checkbox, visibility=VISIBLE, width=96, height=96, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-conn
```

Tried by removing scrollTo and only using click() .But still unable to perform the click.

Comment: Is the `CheckBox` inside a `ScrollView`?

Comment: No, but I tried several options like scrollTo()

Comment: `scrollTo()` expects the target element to be a child of a `ScrollView`, so if your view is going to be too large to fit on screen you'll need to wrap it in a `ScrollView` within the layout XML. Will write up a full answer soon.

Answer (score 1):

The error message you get there states that your `CheckBox` must be both `VISIBLE` and a child of a `ScrollView` or `HorizontalScrollView`. Your `CheckBox` is indeed `VISIBLE`, but is not a child of a `ScrollView`. Therefore if you have a layout like:

```
<LinearLayout ...>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/lbl_license_text" ... />
    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/chk_accept" ... />
</LinearLayout>
```

You need to wrap it inside a `ScrollView` so the view can scroll on smaller-screen devices:

```
<ScrollView ...>
    <LinearLayout ...>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/lbl_license_text" ... />
        <CheckBox android:id="@+id/chk_accept" ... />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

(Obviously replacing instances of `...` with the `android:` properties of that element)

This will allow Espresso to scroll down to the `CheckBox` when running your tests.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by implementing a custom ViewAction function(saw it in one of the answers on stackoverflow)

```
 public static ViewAction setChecked(final boolean checked) {
    return new ViewAction() {
        @Override
        public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
            return new Matcher<View>() {
                @Override
                public boolean matches(Object item) {
                    return isA(Checkable.class).matches(item);
                }

                @Override
                public void describeMismatch(Object item, Description mismatchDescription) {}

                @Override
                public void _dont_implement_Matcher___instead_extend_BaseMatcher_() {}

                @Override
                public void describeTo(Description description) {}
            };
        }

        @Override
        public String getDescription() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void perform(UiController uiController, View view) {
            Checkable checkableView = (Checkable) view;
            checkableView.setChecked(checked);
        }
    };
}
```

and then calling:

```
termsAndConditionsCheckbox.perform(Helper.setChecked(false));
```

to uncheck and passing true to check the checkbox.